# as.name() doesn't work as an argument

Tags: r, rename

I built a function whose return value is named based on its contents.  Using `as.name()` works in the console, but not as a function argument.

```
x <- "newNameforIris"
assign(x, iris)
as.name(x)
# [1] newNameforIris
head(newNameforIris) # gives familiar results (not included)
save(as.name(x), file = "nnfi.bin")
# [1] Error in save(as.name(x), file = "nnfi.bin") : object ‘as.name(x)’ not found
```

I also tried `eval.promises = FALSE`, but to no avail. I don't know the name of the object until the function executes, so I am stuck without `as.name()` or an alternative.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `save()`, specifically the `list` argument

Comment: @RobertHadow, please consider my answer to your old, but effectively unanswered, question. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I discovered this question 2.5 years after it was asked, and because there was not satisfactory answer, I investigated the issue. Here are my findings.

**Investigation:**

Failure reproduced, but the issue is not just `as.name()`.

```
x <- "newNameforIris"
assign(x, iris)
as.name(x)
head(newNameforIris) # as expected
save(as.name(x), file = "nnfi.bin")
# Error in save(as.name(x), file = NULL) : object ‘as.name(x)’ not found
save(as.character(x), file = "nnfi.bin")
# Error in save(as.character(x), file = NULL) : object ‘as.character(x)’ not found
save(eval(as.name(x)), file = "nnfi.bin")
# Error in save(eval(as.name(x)), file = "nnfi.bin") : object ‘eval(as.name(x))’ not found
```

The following succeed.

```
y <- as.name(x)
save(y, file = "nnfi.bin")
save("x", file = "nnfi.bin")
save(list=c("x"), file = "nnfi.bin")
save(list=c(as.character(as.name(x))), file = "nnfi.bin")
```

**Conclusion:**

The `...` argument of `save()` can only accept symbols and characters strings just the as the help file says, "the names of the objects to be saved (as symbols or character strings)".

So let's look at how `save()` processes `...`. Just enter `save`, not `save()`.

```
save
#....
#     names <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
#     list <- c(list, names)
#....
```

Now let's test this with `as.name(x)` and the other failed tests from above.

```
fx <- function(..., list = character()) {
     names <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
     list <- c(list, names)
     return(list)
     }

fx(as.name(x))       # [1] "as.name(x)"
fx(as.character(x))  # [1] "as.character(x)"
fx(eval(as.name(x))) # [1] "eval(as.name(x))"
```

**Answer:**

Items in the `...` argument of `save()` are not evaluated, but rather turned into character strings, so unless these strings are the same as existing objects, the function call will fail.

**Suggestion:**

Use the following.

```
x <- as.name(x)
save(x, file = "nnfi.bin")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the class of `as.name(x)` is `name`.

```
class(as.name(x))
# [1] "name"
```

Try:

```
save(get(x), file = "nnfi.bin")
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `save(list = x, ...)`?

Comment: apologies, my previous answer will only save newNameforIris into the file. The current answer should save the correct data. If you still get errors, you might want to track down in which environmnet the object resides in and use that in your `get`.

Comment: I tried `save(get(x), file = "nnfi.bin")` Result: `object get(x) not found`
What does work for me when x is a character name and df is the object:
`assign(x, iris)`
`save(list = x, file = "nnfi.bin")`  My observation: `get(x)` and `eval(parse(text = x))` don't work so well on the left side of the `<-` but `assign(x, iris)` and `exists(x)` work fine.